# Can't include pagination with React in API request

Tags: reactjs, api, pagination, jsx

I tried now for hours to implement a simple pagination in a clone from hacker news.
This code is working (without pagination):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Article from "./Article.js";
import Header from "./Header.js";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("react");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
 
  const fetchData = (setArticles) => {
    setLoading(true)
    let endpoint = `https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${query}`
    fetch(endpoint)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
        setLoading(false);
        const newArticles = response.hits.map((result) => ({
          text: result.title,
          url: result.url,
          points: result.points,
          comments: result.num_comments,
          author: result.author,
          created: result.created_at_i,
          isCompleted: false
        }))
      .sort((a, b) => (a.num_comments > b.num_comments ? -1:1));
      setArticles(newArticles);
      setQuery(response.query);
    })
    // Error handling
    .catch(error => {
      setLoading(false);
      alert(error);
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchData(setArticles);
      // Automatic data refresh after 5 minutes
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        fetchData(setArticles);
      }, 300000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [query]);

   return (
    <div className="default light">
     
      <div className="container">
        <Header setQuery={setQuery} />
        {/*Display spinner if news are loading*/}
        <div className="loader-container" style={loading ? {display:"block"} : {display:"none"}}> 
          <div className="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <section className="SearchResults" style={loading ? {display:"none"} : {display:"block"}}>
          <div className="SearchResults_container">
            {/*Check if search gave results*/}
            <div className="search-term">{articles.length ? `${articles.length} News about "${query}": ` : `No news found for "${query}"`}</div>
            {articles.map((article, index) => (
              <Article
                key={index}
                index={index}
                article={article}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For the pagination I tried to follow the instructions of this tutorial:
https://medium.com/how-to-react/create-pagination-in-react-js-using-react-hooks-c3c582ff5a96

But even if I take over the complete code and only exchange the link to the source, it won't work anymore.

Does anybody have an idea?

Many thanks and greetings
Bazi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Article from "./Article.js";
import Header from "./Header.js";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("react");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(50); // api support up to a maximum of 50 page only
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

  const fetchData = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    let endpoint = `https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${query}&page=${currentPage}`;
    fetch(endpoint)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
        setLoading(false);
        const newArticles = response.hits.map((result) => ({
          text: result.title,
          url: result.url,
          points: result.points,
          comments: result.num_comments,
          author: result.author,
          created: result.created_at_i,
          isCompleted: false
        }))
      .sort((a, b) => (a.num_comments > b.num_comments ? -1:1));
      setArticles(newArticles);
      setQuery(response.query);
      setPageCount(response.nbPages);
    })
    // Error handling
    .catch(error => {
      setLoading(false);
      alert(error);
    });
  }

  const pageChange = (data) => {
    setCurrentPage(data.selected);
    fetchData();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchData();
      // Automatic data refresh after 5 minutes
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        fetchData();
      }, 300000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [query]);

   return (
    <div className="default light">
      <div className="container">
        <Header setQuery={setQuery} />
        {/*Display spinner if news are loading*/}
        <div className="loader-container" style={loading ? {display:"block"} : {display:"none"}}> 
          <div className="loader"></div>
        </div>
        <section className="SearchResults" style={loading ? {display:"none"} : {display:"block"}}>
          <div className="SearchResults_container">
            {/*Check if search gave results*/}
            <div className="search-term">{articles.length ? `${articles.length} News about "${query}": ` : `No news found for "${query}"`}</div>
            {articles.map((article, index) => (
              <Article
                key={index}
                index={index}
                article={article}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>

       <ReactPaginate
         pageCount={pageCount}
         marginPagesDisplayed={2}
         pageRangeDisplayed={5}
         onPageChange={pageChange}
       />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The idea is to have `onPageChange` callback function to set the current page into state whenever the paginate index changed, and you also need to add `page` param into API call in order to make pagination works.

Also, you want to set `setPageCount` right after every API call in case the total number of pages has changed.

Comment: Hey @kelvin, it works great! And so easy (if you know how to do it). Thanks for your help!